# Solving for ${x}^{{x}^{3}}=5$

Tags: logarithms, lambert-w

I am trying to solve $${x}^{{x}^{3}}=5$$

I took logarithms on both sides, and got  $${x}^{3}\cdot \ln  \left( x \right) -\ln  \left( 5 \right) =0$$

Then I took the help of Maple, when I solve for x the first equation, I get
$$x={{\rm e}^{{\frac {{\rm W} \left(3\,\ln  \left( 5 \right) \right)}{3}
}}}$$

$W$ here is the Lambert W function.

and when I solve for $x$ after taking the logartihms (2nd equation) I get

$$ \left[ \begin {array}{c} x={{\rm e}^{{\it RootOf} \left(  \left( {
{\rm e}^{{\it \_Z}}} \right) ^{3}\cdot {\it \_Z}-\ln  \left( 5
 \right)  \right) }}\end {array} \right] 
$$

Can anyone explain, why there is difference? My 2nd question is how do we come here to using Lambert function?

Comment: Ignoring branching issues I think they are just the same.

Comment: First approach: let $w=\ln(x^3)$ so $we^w=3x^3\ln x=3\ln5$. Second approach: let $z:=\ln x$ so $ze^{3z}-\ln5=0$, which _looks_ like what you inferred, but it's hard to tell in your current notation. For legibility, I advise you note to use `\it` with variables.

Comment: Rather than ${x}^{3}\cdot \ln  \left( x \right) -\ln  \left( 5 \right)=0$, try  $ \ln  \left( x \right)  {x}^{3} = \ln  \left( 5 \right)$ and rewrite this as  $\ln( x) e^{3 \ln(x)}  = \ln( 5)$, and then multiply both sides by $3$ so you can apply the Lambert W function.

Comment: @Henry, can you please explain how Lambert W function came into picture here in case of logarithmic function?

Comment: The Lambert W function provides the solution(s) to $w e^{w} = z$ and here you have $3\ln( x) e^{3 \ln(x)}  =3 \ln( 5)$, i.e. $w=3\ln( x)$ and $z=3 \ln( 5)$, so $3\ln( x)=W(3 \ln( 5))$ and thus $x= e^{{\frac {{ W} \left(3\ln  \left( 5 \right) \right)}{3}}}$

Comment: Thanks alot. Is there any function that can give solution to $w.e^m = z$ ?